# problem with internet explorer in php login page

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers

I have a webpage that logs a user in by checking his username and password and then redirecting him to an admin page.

but it does not redirect to admin page in internet explorer .i am using header function for redirection.

this is the code for login page

```
<?php
include("session.php");
//include("dbconnect.php");
$_SESSION['userid']=$row['id'];
$_SESSION['ses_username']=$row['email'];
$msg=$_GET['msg'];
    if(isset($_POST['sub']) == "sub")
    {
                $user=$_POST['username']; 
                $pwd=$_POST['password']; 
                echo $sqlSel="select * from users where email='".$user."' and password='".$pwd."'"; 
                $res=mysql_query($sqlSel) or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysql_num_rows($res)==0){
                $msg = "Please input Correct Credentials";
        header('location: index.php?msg='.urlencode($msg));
        die();
    }
    else
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
        $_SESSION['userid']=$row['id'];
        $_SESSION['ses_username']=$row['email'];
        echo $_SESSION['name']=$row['first_name']; 
        $_SESSION["loggedIn"]=true;
        header('location: admin.php?name='.urlencode($row['first_name']));
        }
    }   
?>

<div id="myaccountlogin">
<form name="form3" method="post" action="">
    <table width="260" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="4%" height="80">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="11%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="18%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="30%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3" class="name" align="center">User Name:</td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="15" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3" class="name" align="center">Password:</td>
        <td colspan="3">
          <label>
            <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="15" />
            </label>
                </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4" align="right" class="forgotton">Forgotten Password</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="9">&nbsp;</td></tr>

      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="5" align="center" style="padding-right: 40px;"><input type="image" src="images/signin.png" name="sub" value="sub" width="70" height="25" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="6" class="newreg"><a href="registration.php">New Registration</a> | <a href="registration.php"> Sign up </a></td>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
  </div>
```

do sessions cause any problem in IE AS i am saving login details in session??
thanks in advance

Comment: pleas use code-formatting next time (select the code and press the `{}`-sympol)

Comment: Your Code containts SQL-Injections Bugs! REALLY REALLY DANGEROUS! Don't use that CODE on real internet servers!

Comment: You cannot send headers if PHP already outputted something else. Maybe that is the case? Does your PHP warning/notices/errors show you a message "Headers already sent"?

Comment: INTERNET EXPLORER has nothing to do with php or mysql? wtf

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

I've tried your code, but all I can find is that you require $_POST['sub'] to be set, but you don't define an input type="hidden" named "sub", all you have is an input type="image" named "sub" and it looks like IE does not send that as a POST variable. So in IE, PHP never receives $_POST['sub'], that's why it does not redirect.

I still recommend the proper case and the starting slash for the Location: header. Good luck!

**Original answer:**

Not sure, but have you tried:

```
header('Location: /index.php?msg='.urlencode($msg));
```

Comment: Im going to up vote this purely because IE is a pain in the ass, and the chances of it throwing a fit because of case-sensitivity is pretty decent.

Comment: tried this solution but not working .the value are posted given in form but redirect back to same page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cookies then you have to set full permissions for cookies to access the content in IE.
This can be recognised by the saturn(planet) symbol near the start menu but in your right side so click it and set the permissions @ that time you will be able to login.

Comment: its work fine in mozilla, Google crome . i had tried this one cookies are enable in settings.